# TypeScript types for React Native's measure callback within a onLayout event?

Tags: typescript, react-native

How can I add TypeScript types to a `measure` callback within the `onLayout` event?

```
  <View
    ref={containerViewRef}
    onLayout={() => {
      if (containerViewRef.current) {
        containerViewRef?.current?.measure(
          (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY): MeasureOnSuccessCallback => {
            setPageY(pageY);
          },
        );
      }
    }}
  >
```

`measure` has this error:

> TS2339: Property 'measure' does not exist on type 'never'.

And `MeasureOnSuccessCallback` has this error:

> TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: Did you try removing ?s from `containerViewRef?.current?`

Comment: I can simplify it to " onLayout={() => { containerViewRef.current?.measure( " but I get the same error

Comment: @Eldar why remove the optional chaining operator? It does not make any sense on how that could solve TS issues. Also @Evanss you don't have to check for the `current` existence when you use optional chaining operator, that's what it's there for, to do these checks for you.

Comment: @ChristosLytras it was just an assumption. Because in the if statement it is already checked that it is not null and later it is assumed that still it is nullable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the following package versions:

```js
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
```

the following snippet produces no errors:

```
const Test = () => {
  const containerViewRef = useRef<View>(null);

  const [, setPageY] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View
      ref={containerViewRef}
      onLayout={() => {
        containerViewRef.current?.measure(
          (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            setPageY(pageY);
          },
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Changes you need:

1) annotate your ref as `const containerViewRef = useRef<View>(null);`

2) remove `MeasureOnSuccessCallback` type annotation - it will be inferred by TS. (In your example it annotates the return value of the callback and not the callback itself, as it should).

Comment: All I was missing was the <View> type for useRef.

Comment: Yes, as @Evanss mentions, for TypeScript users the `View` type argument is crucial!